# CSS Div tag not working

Tags: php, html, css, styles

I'm trying to use a div tag to add CSS to a page that I include with `include 'login.php';` inside the `<div>` tag but the css doesn't seem to be working. My ultimate goal is to get the form to overlay the page but right now I just want some sort of styling to work so I can go from there.

**EDIT:** Turns out my stylesheet doesn't register or connect to the document because it works if I use the style tags to create a stylesheet inside index.php. No idea what I did wrong, dreamweaver recognizes it.

index.php

```
<div id="login">
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && strcmp($_GET['action'], "login") == 0) {
        include 'Users/loginPopUp.php';
    }
?>
</div>
```

loginPopUp.php

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="usn">Username : </label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="username" />
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="passwd">Password : </label>
                <input type="password" maxlength="30" required name="password" />
            </li>
            <li class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log me in" />
                <input type="button" name="register" value="Register" onclick="location.href='register.php'" />
            </li>

        </ul>
    </form>
```

style.css

```
#login{
    background:#F00;
}
```

Comment: If you use position fixed, the width: 100% and float right will have no effect. set width: 100px for example will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add the CSS File to the header of the page.

Second, once you've done that just add div="#login" in the form tag.

Comment: Add position: absolute and under that add position: fixed

Comment: If you still can't see the form, look into "z-index" on W3School

Comment: I can see the form, it just doesn't have a background color. I editted the Style.css

Comment: @Duck That may be because your form is floating or has a position property that is causing `#login` to ignore its height. We can't tell from the code you provided.

Comment: @TreeTree right now, Im just trying to get some sort of css to apply to it

Answer (score 0):

Probably your div has no height as the form is floated or similar. Try:

```
#login{
    background-color:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: no change. I can manually add style to the form but I cant get any divs to work, form or no form on my page. The Style is added in the header and dreamweaver recognizes them but they don't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

i think the CSS style are loaded only after when the DIV is called. It might be at the end of the page....

Comment: elaborate please? I replaced my `<link>` tag with a `<style>` tag and put all my CSS in the main document and it works